# Modified conjugate gradient method to minimise quadratic functional restricted to positive solutions

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-optimization

Knowing that CG is an efficient method of solving sparse systems of linear equations, I have used it to solve a linear system of equations generated by a finite element algorithm.

In order to impose an additional boundary condition, I have to ensure that the components of the solution are greater than or equal to zero, resulting in a slightly modified version of the minimisation problem

$ x_{*} = \arg \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(x), \quad \varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^T x, $

specifically

$ x_{*} = \arg \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^n} \varphi(x), \quad \varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^T x. $

How would I go about modifying the conjugate gradient algorithm to include this restriction?

Comment: I don't know if it is easy to alter the CG solver to do that, but I am quite sure you can find some regularization that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this paper for a generalization of CG type methods to non-negative constrained setting: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/986317/